# What is the return type of scala case class?

Tags: scala

Given the code:

```
abstract class activity {
  case class Fun(sports: String, eat: String) extends activity

  val fun = Fun("soccer","apple")
}
```

What is the return type of fun?

Comment: you can see its return type from Scala REPL and that's fun, but it's `Fun` :)

Comment: fun is of class Fun, right?

Comment: A class doesn't have a return type.

Answer (score 1):

`fun` is neither a function nor a method, so it has no return type. `fun` is of type `Fun`.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. It's a recursive dependency on `activity` class. The type should be `Fun`. But if you try to instantiate some concrete class and access the member:

```
abstract class activity {

  case class Fun(sports: String,eat:String) extends activity

  val fun = Fun("soccer","apple")

}

object Main extends App {

  class concrete extends activity
  val x = new concrete // StackOverflowError exception!

}
```

you get an `StackOverflowError` exception. Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: Sure! by creating fun - you're creating new activity, by  creating activity - you're creating new fun and so on :)))

Comment: Indeed. But it won't be that `Fun` to have code throwing `StackOverflowError` because a mistake of the programmer and the compiler not detecting such redundant case. Or maybe the compiler can't? :)

Comment: In general case no, but if you have a recursive dependency like this (and since the compiler has the full class hierarchy available), and at some moment you try to instantiate some object, I think it should at least warn you about trying to do something that would throw. True that it's not an usual case, but where is the type safety motto then?

Comment: The type-safety you're talking about is guaranteed only in languages with full typed systems and automated theorem prooving - which scala is even nearly don't, more than that such languages could be not turing-complete. But you're right that some macro for example could do such check and print some warning about.

Comment: and you know - if the code have at least one implicit or explicit "if" inside - situation gets much more complicated

Comment: You are right about that. But now I wonder, when would you want to extend from an abstract class which contains a member of the extended class? What would be a use case for that? I think the language shouldn't not allow such confusing semantics to actually pass the compilation, when they can be detected at compile-time. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment

Comment: It's more style-related - I could `trait Model { case class A extends Model }` and at least it will work fine (while i'm not instantiating A). I could use it to generate path dependent A's from themselves, for DSL and so on:  `scala> new Model {}; new res5.A; new res6.A`. And it doesn't violates POLA here as you got exactly what you expect. It's consistent and you can assume stack overflow reason without any additional readings, except basic language knowledge.

Comment: it could violate POLA - if I had to say smthing like "oh, it's exceptional situation, see this 100500-pages of documentation" to explain the exception. On the other hand such code itself may violate KISS principle, so compiler (or some code-style tool) have full right to warn user about that (maybe in some special mode)

Comment: It's not an exceptional situation. The code does exactly what it looks like it does. A "special mode", on the other hand, *would* violate POLA.

Comment: @Imm "it's not an exceptional situation" - yes, that's my point. By "special mode" I mean ask compiler/IDE/build-tool to run additional checks for bad style - it's not even related to POLA as it's just some independent helper (you can live without it) and it's obvious that you should use such tool to check code-style. "The code-style is more what you'd call "guidelines" than actual rules"(c)

Answer (score 0):

It's of type `Fun`

```
abstract class activity {
  case class Fun(sports: String, eat: String) extends activity

  val fun: Fun = Fun("soccer", "apple")
}
```

When you do `Fun("soccer", "apple")` it boils down to `Fun.apply("soccer", "apple")` and the default `apply` method of case classes companion object's returns an instance of the class, therefore it has return type `Fun`.